# Getting the page source of imgur

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get the page source of an imgur website using requests, but the results I'm getting are different from the source. I understand that these pages are rendered using JS, but that is not what I am searching for.

It seems I'm getting redirected because they detect I'm using an automated browser, but I'd prefer not to use selenium here. For example, see the following code to scrape the page source of two imgur ID's (one valid ID and one invalid ID) with different page sources.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "https://i.imgur.com/ssXK5" #valid ID
url2 = "https://i.imgur.com/ssXK4" #invalid ID

def get_source(url):
    headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Mobile Safari/537.36"}

    page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

page1 = get_source(url1)
page2 = get_source(url2)

print(page1==page2)
#True
```

The scraped page sources are identical, so I presume it's an anti-scraping thing. I know there is an imgur API, but I'd like to know how to circumvent such a redirection, if possible. Is there any way to get the actual source code using the requests module?

Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be an explicit redirect in your urls: https://i.imgur.com/ssXK5 -> https://imgur.com/ssXK5 have you tried just get rid of that `i.` part?

Comment: Yes I have, but it makes no difference.

Comment: It's because of the headers you are using. Replace your current one with this `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I got my headers by inspecting the network tab, but I presume your headers can generally be used?